# Express each of these sentences in terms of $Q(x, y)$, quantifiers, and logical connectives,

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Let Q(x,y) be the statement “x has been a contestant on quiz show y”, where the
domain of x is the set of students and the domain for y consists of all
quiz shows. For each of the English sentences below, please express it in terms of
$Q(x,y)$ with quantifiers.

Please Correct me:

(i) Alice has never appeared in Jeopardy. $\quad\exists x \exists y \neg Q(x,y) $

(ii) Every quiz show has had a student as a contestant. $\quad \forall y \exists x Q(x,y)$

(iii) No student has appeared in both Wheel of Fortune and Family Feud:

- $\neg \exists x_1\neg \exists x_2 Q((x_1, \text{Wheel of Fortune}) \land \exists x_2 Q(x_2, \text{Family Feud}))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Let $Q(x,y)$ be the statement “$x$ has been a contestant on quiz show $y$”,

  - the domain of $x$ is the set of students and
  - the domain for $y$ consists of all quiz shows.

---

> (i) Alice has never appeared in Jeopardy.

- Let $a$: Alice (assuming Alice is a student).
- Let $j$: jeopardy.
- Then we have,  $\lnot Q(a, j)\tag{i}$
- Given (i), it is certainly true that your translation "$\exists x \exists y \neg Q(x,y)$" follows from (i): "There is some student x and some quiz show y such that $Q(x, y)$".

  - But your translation is *not a translation of the given sentence*:  Your translation says nothing to the effect that "*Alice* has never been a contestant of *jeopardy*".
  - A quantifier is not appropriate* here. We need only the *predicate* $Q(x, y)$, where "x" is replaced by a named constant for "Alice", and "y" is replaced by a named constant for "Jeopardy".

> (ii) Every quiz show has had a student as a contestant.

- Yes, you're correct:  $\forall y \exists x Q(x,y)\tag{ii}$Nice work!

> (iii) No student has appeared in both Wheel of Fortune and Family Feud.

- We need only *one* variable to represent a student, and we need only *one* quantifier: 

  Here, we want to say something like:

  - "There does not exist a student x (or there is no student x) such that (x has appeared in Wheel of Fortune AND x has appeared in Family Feud)".
  - Equivalently, we can state "for all students x, it is not the case that (x has appeared in Wheel of Fortune AND x has appeared in Family Feud)."
- To simplify matters, let's let

  - $f: $ Family feud
  - $w: $ Wheel of Fortune

$\neg\exists x (Q(x, w) \land Q(x, f))\quad\equiv\quad \forall x \lnot(Q(x, w) \land Q(x, f))\tag{iii}$

- Can you see why your answer for (iii) is problematic? Try translating it into natural language and see if it matches the original sentence.

Comment: Yes of course -- but here surely we should be giving *hints* for elementary homework, not saving the poster the effort of doing any thinking ....

Comment: I'd suggest for (ii): $\forall y\exists x\colon S(x)\land Q(x,y)$, where $S(x)$ denoets "$x$ is a student".

Comment: @Hagen The domain for x is "all students".

Comment: @Peter it appears to me that the asker has applied some effort to the problem. *Pointing out what's wrong*, in and of itself, does not necessarily help.

Comment: @amWhy (a) Call me an old cynic, but the "effort" seemed quite suspiciously hopeless, according to the plan "bung down *anything* and then ask for the right answer". (b) And I did give a hint or two. Yours, Old Cynic.

Comment: @PeterSmith (a) perhaps hopelessly suspicious? Personally, I try to give the benefit of doubt, but I've reached the "hopelessly suspicious" point, too. Perhaps I haven't taught long enough yet! Typically, if you follow my answers, I prefer to provide hints..., or ask leading questions. (b) Fair enough, yes you did give a couple of hints. (c) I do try to avoid words like "obviously" or "plainly" - but again, that's because I tend to trust that questions are genuine. (If it were "plainly" clear to the OP, why post?)

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

(i) is plainly wrong -- you need a constant denoting Jeopardy rather than the second quantifier.

(iii) is plainly wrong -- what you have written implies no one has ever appeared in Wheel of Fortune. You only need a single quantifier.

Comment: (i) Why leave out the need for a constant denoting Alice?